# Password field would not render

Tags: python, django, forms

Password field is not rendering

**My forms.py looks like this:**

```
from django import forms

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
  username =forms.CharField()
  password =forms.PasswordInput()
  email =forms.EmailField(label='E-Mail')
  gender =forms.ChoicField(choices=[('Male', 'male'), ('Female', 'female')])
```

When I run it every other field shows except for the password field.

Comment: `PasswordInput` is *not* a formfield. `CHarField` is a formfield`, `PasswordInput` is a *widget*.

Answer (score 1):

The PasswordInput method is not a field. It's a widget to format your char fields. Try:

```
password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use. maybe it will help.

```
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Davi Nakamura Cardoso and@Shaid Hasan Shawon for your time and help. It worked.